# How can I split across a dimension in a numpy array if it's not equally divisible?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` array of `(584, 161)` shape. I want to split this so that it's `(6, 100, 161)`, but in the last row(?), right pad the elements with a `0`.

So if I had `(1412, 161)`, it should be converted to `(15, 100, 161)` with 88 `0`'s in the last row on the right

Comment: I think (584,161) has to convert to (6, 100, 61), not (5, 100, 61). Right?

Comment: Flatten it then pad it then reshape it.

Comment: Just figure out how many new rows you need to come out even, and `concatenate` them on.  Then reshape.   In the first case `np.zeros((16,161))`, and in the second `np.zeros((88,161))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(584, 161)
arr = np.append(arr, np.zeros((16, 161)), axis=0)
arr = arr.reshape((6, 100, 161))
```

or

```
arr = np.random.rand(584, 161)
arr_zero = np.zeros((16, 161))
arr = np.concatenate((arr, arr_zero), axis=0)
arr = arr.reshape((6, 100, 161))
```

Comment: `append` works fine here, though I prefer to see `np.concatenate`.  `np.append` is too often misused.

Comment: @hpaulj can you edit the answer accordingly please?